# How to use AdapterView.INVALID_ROW_ID?

Tags: java, android

Sorry, for this dumb question...

But I can't understand how I should write correctly. Here is what I want:

```
long selectedCartId = cartsSpinner.getSelectedItemId();
if (selectedCartId !=  AdapterView.INVALID_ROW_ID)
     CartDataSource.insertProduct(selectedCartId, prodId, count);
```

but eclipse generates error for the if-condition:

> Incompatible operand types long and Class< INVALID_ROW_ID>

---

[**INVALID_ROW_ID**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#INVALID_ROW_ID) is declared as this:

```
public abstract class android.widget.AdapterView extends android.view.ViewGroup {

// <Skipped>

    public static final long INVALID_ROW_ID = -9223372036854775808L;

}
```

Comment: works fine for me. Are you sure the error is on that line?

Comment: Hmmm... after cleaning the project the error has gone. Arrrg (angry) :) Thx, zapl!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in not cleared project.